# How to invoke multi threading in SAS Base(https://www.sas.com/) on AMD processor(32core) and Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: multithreading, sorting, sas, amd-processor

I can't observe on my AMD-machine parallel execution  of any elementary SAS Base procedures namely :proc sort,proc means , etc, which should run multithreading automatically according to the [SAS Base documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.5&docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n0n5mm9l2pmpevn1lsjqccmgp8tx.htm&locale=en#p0fbq4inzwf57bn1xrcss87xxj8t).

What did i do:

1. I've tried to set-up number of my physical cores(of my AMD machine) in SAS Base manually:
   `options threads cpucount=32 MEMSIZE=630621054720;`
   Then I checked with : `proc options group=performance;` and observed the resulting settings:

```
Group=PERFORMANCE 
 CPUCOUNT=32       Specifies the number of processors that thread-enabled applications should assume are available for concurrent processing.
MEMSIZE=212697166080 Specifies the limit on the amount of virtual memory that can be used during a SAS session.
SORTSIZE=53687091200 Specifies the amount of memory that is available to the SORT procedure.
```

2. Yet on my another Intel Core i7 4790k machine, the same SAS Base installations runs multithreading perfectly.
3. Also multicore-execution works perfectly on my AMD ryzen 3970x machine with any other programs and IDEs:

   - C#
   - python
   - matlab

My AMD SAS installation specification:

```
---Operating System:   WX64_WKS.
---Base SAS Software                                                                                    
---SAS/STAT                                                                                             
---SAS/GRAPH                                                                                            
---SAS Enterprise Miner                                                                                 
---SAS Enterprise Guide                                                                                
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files                                                                     
---SAS Enterprise Miner for Desktop                                                                     
---SAS Workspace Server for Local Access                                                                
---High Performance Suite                                                                               
---SAS Add-in for Microsoft Excel     


 
-  Version SAS Enterprise Guide: 7.100.0.2002
-  Version  SAS Base: 9402.0.21456.22399
-  Used Memory: 384 372 736 bytes
-  Client procedure: Running on console
-  Working in WOW64 (32-bit subsystrm): NO
-  Operating as 64-bit version: YES

--- Opearating system ---
-  Name: Windows 8
-  Version: 6.2.0.9200
-  .NET Runtime Version: 4.0.30319.42000 (no service pack)

- AUTOMATIC SYSHOSTINFOLONG X64_7PRO WIN 6.1.7600  Workstation
- AUTOMATIC SYSNCPU 32  
- AUTOMATIC SYSPROCESSMODE SAS Workspace Server
- AUTOMATIC SYSPROCESSNAME Object Server
- AUTOMATIC SYSPROCNAME 
- AUTOMATIC SYSRC 0
- AUTOMATIC SYSSCP WIN
- AUTOMATIC SYSSCPL X64_7PRO
```

Answer (score 3):

Enable `options msglevel=i` then run `proc means`. The log will tell you if multithreading is being used.

```
options msglevel=i;

proc means data=sashelp.cars;
run;
```

Log:

```
NOTE: Multiple concurrent threads will be used to summarize data.
NOTE: There were 428 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CARS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE MEANS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.04 seconds
      cpu time            0.03 seconds
```

Comment: Thank you Stu Sztukowski, you seem pretty examined with the SAS.
The output:
`25         proc means data=sashelp.cars;
26         run;

NOTE: Multiple concurrent threads will be used to summarize data.
NOTE: There were 428 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CARS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE MEANS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.06 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds`

Comment: Stu, consider please my example, that runs in parallel in Windows7 +Intel4790k and not parallel in Windows10+ ADM ryzen3790x:

Comment: `data RandData;
    array x(1e4);
    do nrows=1 to 1e5;
 flag=abs(ceil( rand('uniform') -0.5));
   if nrows<7e4 then  map=0;else map=1;
         do nvars=1 to dim(x);
             x(nvars) = ceil(10*rand('uniform'));
         end;
         output;
    end;
run;
 proc sql; select distinct map, mean(flag), count(*) from RandData group by map;quit;
options msglevel=i;
proc glmselect data=RandData (where=( map  =0 )  )  valdata=RandData (where=( map =1))  ;
performance DETAILS; model flag  = x: /  details=all stats=all selection=LASSO  (steps=1240  choose=validate); run;`

Comment: Ironically when I ran your full example on my smaller AMD machine, I got a Stack Overflow error! Is there some sort of badge for getting a stack overflow error on Stack Overflow? Anyway, after slimming down the number of variables and running both on an AMD and Intel machine, threading was enabled and working. What do your `glmselect` performance metrics say?

Comment: Quesiton1. Can you please tell me how to see the performance metrics , produced by glmselect?  Quesiton2.  Was your CPU fully 100% engaged into calculation of glmselect? Because I observe  only 4 cores out of 23 employed in calculus. That's pretty disappointing. May be you know how to force sas use all cores while carrying out "proc glmselect"? May be sas can't obseve more than 4 cores in general?

Comment: SAS will identify how many cores to use for solving a particular problem in glmselect and use the maximum that it can. For example, using multiple by-groups will invoke more cores since by-groups can all be calculated in parallel. Some aspects of linear regression can be parallelized whereas others cannot. SAS can use as many cores as available and required depending on the procedure and the number of groups you're using. For example, proc HPREG may use cores differently compared to glmselect. SAS HP procedures are designed around parallel processing and may exploit cores more efficiently.

Comment: For example, in HPREG you can use the `performance` option and force 8 threads; however, it may not necessarily improve performance depending on what your regression is.

Comment: Stu, i got a question for you: Why does SAS see only 4 of my cores when I start it? "proc options group=performance;" gives on start CPUCOUNT=4     . I run glmselect as usual and observe that ony 4 of my cores are employed by glmselect. Than I  run "options threads cpucount=32 MEMSIZE=630621054720;"   start glmselect - and  again observe only 4 cores employed in process explorer. May be i've installed SAS incorrect? May be my version of SAS BASE issued in 2015 can't  see more than 4 AMD cores? How to dig into this direction? what procedures to run , to test my hypothesis?

Comment: By the way "proc hplogistic" has proven to load my 32cores at 100% of capacity!! Some magic things are happening with my SAS Base 9.4

Comment: The reason why it only sees 4 on startup is due to the system default. SAS will set `cpucount=4` on a default installation. You can edit this value to be all of your cores by adding the following line to `...SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\nls\en\sasv9.cfg`:  `-CPUCOUNT ACTUAL`. You can also create a file named `autoexec.sas`, save it in `...SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4`, and add the line `options cpucount=actual;`. You only need to do one of them, but either will always use the full CPU count. SAS `HP` procs are tuned for high performance, distributed, or multithreaded environments.

Comment: So, experimentally I've derived the maximum allowed number of cores glmselect can employ is: 22.  If I run `options threads cpucount=23 MEMSIZE=80G REALMEMSIZE=80G; proc glmselect data=table ***` I see that calculation is done on a single core. If I submit  `options threads cpucount=22 ` then  all the 22 cores are employed. My hypothesis: maybe SAS glmselect is adjusting the maximum core-number dependent on my physical memory, which is 128 GB. Yet  passing  `options  cpucount=23  MEMSIZE=800G REALMEMSIZE=800G` still drew one pathetic сore for calculus. Stu, any idea what's shaking and how fix?

Comment: Sadly that one I cannot exactly determine, but if you contact SAS Tech Support with your findings and sample code they can get you in touch with someone in R&D to help explain the results. You'll get a response in a few days or less. I'd be curious to hear what they say.

Answer (score 0):

So, experimentally I've derived the maximum allowed number of cores glmselect can employ is: 22. If I run options threads cpucount=23 MEMSIZE=80G REALMEMSIZE=80G; proc glmselect data=table *** I see that calculation is done on a single core. If I submit options threads cpucount=22  then all the 22 cores are employed. My hypothesis: maybe SAS glmselect is adjusting the maximum core-number dependent on my physical memory, which is 128 GB. Yet passing options  cpucount=23  MEMSIZE=800G REALMEMSIZE=800G still drew one pathetic сore for calculus. Will be getting in touch with SAS support